# Failed to start Php7.4 FastCGI because extant file does not exist

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

From what I can tell this appears to be a common issue that is usually fixed by removing php from the machine and reinstalling it, however I get the same error message when trying to uninstall php that I get trying to start it.
Below is the entire message I receive when I run any of the following commands:

```
systemctl status php7.4-fpm.service (gives less info but still same error)
apt install php7.4-fpm
sudo apt -f install
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt-get remove --purge php
```

```
NOTICE: Not enabling PHP 7.4 FPM by default.
NOTICE: To enable PHP 7.4 FPM in Apache2 do:
NOTICE: a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif
NOTICE: a2enconf php7.4-fpm
NOTICE: You are seeing this message because you have apache2 package installed.
Job for php7.4-fpm.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status php7.4-fpm.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript php7.4-fpm, action "restart" failed.
● php7.4-fpm.service - The PHP 7.4 FastCGI Process Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/php7.4-fpm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2022-04-26 19:45:11 UTC; 7ms ago
       Docs: man:php-fpm7.4(8)
    Process: 869418 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/php-fpm7.4 --nodaemonize --fpm-config /etc/php/7.4/fpm/php-fpm.conf (code=exited, status=78)
    Process: 869438 ExecStopPost=/usr/lib/php/php-fpm-socket-helper remove /run/php/php-fpm.sock /etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/www.conf 74 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 869418 (code=exited, status=78)

Apr 26 19:45:11 domjudge systemd[1]: Starting The PHP 7.4 FastCGI Process Manager...
Apr 26 19:45:11 domjudge php-fpm7.4[869418]: [26-Apr-2022 19:45:11] ERROR: failed to open configuration file '/etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/domjudge.conf': No such file or directory (2)
Apr 26 19:45:11 domjudge php-fpm7.4[869418]: [26-Apr-2022 19:45:11] ERROR: Unable to include /etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/domjudge.conf from /etc/php/7.4/fpm/php-fpm.conf at line 145
Apr 26 19:45:11 domjudge php-fpm7.4[869418]: [26-Apr-2022 19:45:11] ERROR: failed to load configuration file '/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php-fpm.conf'
Apr 26 19:45:11 domjudge php-fpm7.4[869418]: [26-Apr-2022 19:45:11] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
Apr 26 19:45:11 domjudge systemd[1]: php7.4-fpm.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=78/CONFIG
Apr 26 19:45:11 domjudge systemd[1]: php7.4-fpm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 26 19:45:11 domjudge systemd[1]: Failed to start The PHP 7.4 FastCGI Process Manager.
dpkg: error processing package php7.4-fpm (--configure):
 installed php7.4-fpm package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 php7.4-fpm
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I would assume that the solution is as simple as determining why domjudge.conf doesn't exist, but when trying to run
`ln -s domserver/etc/domjudge-fpm.conf /etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/domjudge.conf` 
I get the output
ln: failed to create symbolic link `'/etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/domjudge.conf': File exists`

Any assistance here would be great.

Comment: Issue ended up being a corrupted .conf file in /etc/apache2/conf-available, solution was to copy the .conf to that location rather than create a link